# Eigrp topology table

Tags: networking, cisco, eigrp

This is a cisco networking question

does Eigrp topology table 
contains the entire network topology on it's database!
I am a bit confused in this, can someone let me know!
thank you

Answer (score 1):

EIGRP falls under the category of distance vector routing protocols which means that it "routes by rumor". So the topology table does only contain information which it has received from its neighbors which is not necessarily all information about the network since distance vector protocols only tell their neighbors about the best routes as opposed to link state protocols like OSPF which tells each other everything in a given area.

Answer (score -2):

This topology have one main switch and main switch divide network to sub-Switch or Sub-Switch directly contact clients nodes . whenever client node send any request to server its works like client Node to Sub-Switch to main Switch to Server

Comment: no, you missed my point completely. I think topology table cant have the entire topology if it has other routing protocols on it's network